# Accumulate changing value in Excel Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently running a trading algo in excel that utilizes live data so the value of my A1 cell keeps changing.

For example:

```
A1 = 3     at 930
A1 = 2     at 931
A1 = 100   at 932
```

A1s value changes throughout the and I would like to add those values up continusly.

So in my example the answer would be 105.

Is there any way to accumulate the values of the cell A1 in excel? I don't care about the time, I just need the value.

I don't have VBA that changes the value. Its actually a Bloomberg Terminal add-in that is feeding the data in.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have VBA that changes what is in A1?  if you do you could easily add lines of code to do what you want.

Comment: What if it updates to the same value?  Would you want to add that as well?  (In your example, if the second value was also 3, would you want a total of 103 or 106?)

Comment: Do you really want to add them constantly, which would get rather large, or average them?

Answer (score 3):

Use the on worksheet change event and save the result in a different cell. Put this code in the code fot the sheet in question.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Static lLong As Long

If Cells(1, 1).Value <> lLong Then
    lLong = Cells(1, 1).Value

    Cells(2, 1).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value + Cells(1, 1).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Edit:

Ok after reading jerussels comments I see it needs to be a bit more complicated. You need to store the variable as a global variable and the workbook open event has to be used to store the initial value.

Also as tigeravatar says it is probably best as a double if there is a chance of fractions.

So a the top of the a standard module you need the line

```
dim gdDouble as double
```

In the workbook code you need:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    gdDouble = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Replace "sheet1" with the sheets name.

In the sheet you need

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Cells(1, 1).Value <> gdDouble Then
    gdDouble = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Cells(2, 1).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value + Cells(1, 1).Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: May want to use Double instead of Long just in case A1 contains a decimal, like 4.5

Comment: This also fails for the first time the sheet is opened because the Static variable hasn't been set yet.  Therefore that If Statement is true because iLong has never been given a value.  Meaning, if somebody opens the sheet, and changes a value in a cell OTHER THAN A1 the code will add whatever is in A1 to A2, despite the fact that A1 has NOT changed.

Comment: Yep, I like that one better.. :)